# Split string on "\\" and/or "/" using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, split

How can I split the following string on "\" and/or "/" using LINQ

I say and/or for "\" and "/" because in my file paths, I might end up getting forward slashes only, backslashes only or a mix of both.

```
 "temp\\SimpleRec/bin/Debug/Geming.SimpleRec.vshost.exe"

 "temp\\SimpleRec\\bin\\Debug\\Geming.SimpleRec.vshost.exe"

 "temp/SimpleRec/bin/Debug/Geming.SimpleRec.vshost.exe"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why use LINQ and not `string.Split`?

Comment: my solution does not use `Split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split()` seems to be the best option here, but just for fun it is also possible to do with LINQ.

[One of my implementations](https://gist.github.com/1815851) of [String Calculator Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) uses this approach (no `Split` at all). See `InternalAdd()` method. I took functional approach with head and tail. You divide string to head and tail using `.Take()` and return head + recursive result of calling the same function for tail.

Sample code for one char delimiter is below (things are getting complicated when delimiters are getting longer):

```
    private IEnumerable<string> BreakString(string source)
    {
        var delimiter = '/';
        var head = source.TakeWhile(c => c != delimiter);
        if (!head.Any())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        var tail = source.SkipWhile(c => c != delimiter)
            .Skip(1);
        yield return String.Join("", head);
        foreach (var t in BreakString(String.Join("", tail)))
        {
            yield return t;
        }

    }


// usage
from s in BreakString(source)
```

You can also go further and get rid of `String.Join()` by `tail.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => sb.Append(c)).ToString();`

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of work just to split a string. :)

Comment: agree 100%, but its a good exercise for daily Kata :) Also internal implementation of `String.Split` may be complicated as well.

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with a mental exercise...  though I'd be worried if the internal implementation of `String.Split` as overly complex :)

Comment: @theJoric, true... but most of that looks like edge-cases :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ for this:

```
string[] values = myString.Split(new []{'\\', '/'});
```

Introducing LINQ for such a task just adds complexity and reduces readability.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I think that LINQ is attempted to be used for everything, when it doesn't.

```
string[] data = myString.Split(new Char[]{'\\', '/'});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use LinQ here, the default Split() method will do the work:

```
var path = "temp\\SimpleRec/bin/Debug/Geming.SimpleRec.vshost.exe"
var parts = path.Split(new[] { '/', '\\' });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can split using LINQ by following way:

```
var list=from item in str.Split(new string[] { "\\","/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
         select item;
```

Comment: LINQ makes no sense here. Result would be the same as `str.Split(new [] { "\\","/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: @the_joric: Wajih was just curious about the implemenation of LINQ in this scenario.....So,provide the solution with LINQ......

Answer (score 0):

No LINQ required, simply do this:

```
var path = @"temp\\SimpleRec/bin/Debug/Geming.SimpleRec.vshost.exe";
var split = path.Split(new [] { '/', '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```